# How do I add a Sitecore Form using Sitecore Experience Accelerator?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

I am following the instructions on page https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-form.html

It mentions after adding a Sitecore Form Wrapper that I should then be able to drag across MVC Form.  However I still can only see the two form wrappers:

[image: Screen doesn't match described behaviour in documentation]

Have I missed installing something or is there a trick to it that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were doing it correctly.

Just save the page and sitecoreFormsWrapper-1 placeholder should appear inside Sitecore Form Wrapper component.

Then you will see in Toolbox the MVC Form component:

[image]

Comment: Strangely it wasn't appearing in my Toolbox, but when I clicked the Add here (after selecting the wrapper) I could select it.  Thanks!